# How to implement string.rfind in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

In Lua there's only `string.find`, but sometime `string.rfind` is needed. For example, to  parse directory and file path like:

```
fullpath = "c:/abc/def/test.lua"
pos = string.rfind(fullpath,'/')
dir = string.sub(fullpath,pos)
```

How to write such `string.rfind`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `string.match`:

```
fullpath = "c:/abc/def/test.lua"
dir = string.match(fullpath, ".*/")
file = string.match(fullpath, ".*/(.*)")
```

Here in the pattern, `.*` is greedy, so that it will match as much as it can before it matches `/`

**UPDATE**:

As @Egor Skriptunoff points out, this is better:

```
dir, file = fullpath:match'(.*/)(.*)'
```

Comment: dir, file = fullpath:match'(.*/)(.*)'

Answer (score 4):

Yu & Egor's answer works. Another possibility using find would be to reverse the string:

```
pos = #s - s:reverse():find("/") + 1
```

Comment: This gives the same result: `pos = s:match'.*()/'`

Comment: Do notice that in general reversing the string also reverses the substring you're looking for.